# Best way to convert Map<DateTime, List<int>> to Map<DateTime, int> where List[0] is the value?

Tags: dart

I want to graph my data

```
  Map<DateTime, List> data;
```

The list has different values from my SQL database, but I only want the first index of the list to be the Y value.

How do I convert it easily to

```
Map<DateTime, int> inputData
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```dart
Map<DateTime, List<int>> data = ...;
var inputData = {for (var e in data.entries) e.key: e.value.first};
```